# Preview not Showing in Android 3.0 Canary

Tags: android, android-studio, preview

I have started using Latest Android Studio 3.0 but I am having a problem with Preview. It's not showing Preview in Preview Tab.
Here is what I have done

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/activePlanCard"
                layout="@layout/layout_item_activated_plan" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/DashView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/activePlanCard"
                android:background="@drawable/drw_dash_line" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/provideAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/DashView"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="Provide Address Detail :" />
      </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

Your assistance in this matter will be greatly appreciated

Thanks..

[image: Here I've attached preview ScreenShort]

Comment: canary are generally not stable versions. They always have problem with preview. Revert to the older version of studio and wait till beta release.

Comment: Thanks, @VivekMishra, It's working fine in older version but I'm using latest version for my current project

Comment: 3.0 introduces many interesting functionalities, finally java 8 support without jack (so Instant Run should work) and instant apps support. However, I would never recommend to use Canary version on production. Bugs are expected.

Comment: Problem persists on the released stable version.

Answer (score 11):

The following change solved this for me:

In the styles.xml (app > res > values), in the base application theme - add "base" before the parent style.

From:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

To:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: What do we do if the AppTheme is **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar**?

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar works as it is in my code with the issue, without any change. So that I wouldn't know.

Comment: Interestingly I changed my style according you mentioned so that I could get the preview back. It worked fine. Then when I got back to **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** surprisingly the problem was gone. Very strange tho. Thanks for the tip anyways

Comment: This fixed my issue for "ActionBarOverlayLayout" but do you how to fix similar issue but for "coordinatorLayout"? @AnetteKleffelgaard

Comment: Thanks man! it worked. PS. Problem was in stable channel as well in AS 3.0.1. It works for me now after this change. :-)

Answer (score 0):

hey I had the same problem and i solved it like this:
in build.gradle(app) edit the following lines like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0' 

targetSdkVersion 25

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was build a new project in Studio 3.0, which worked fine in rendering xml in the design window.  I then took all the settings related to sdk versions and compile in dependencies in the new gradle.build APP file and applied them to the gradle.build APP file in the App that was not rendering.  I changed to the following:

```
compileSdkVersion 26

targetSdkVersion 26

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

I cleaned and rebuilt the project.  At this point I got the following build error:

Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0

Add Google Maven repository and sync project

Show in File

Show in Project Structure dialog

I added the Maven repository and cleaned and rebuilt the project.  All xml rendering worked after that!