# Android Studio does not show layout after updating to version 3.0.1

Tags: android, xml, ide, android-studio-3.0

I updated Android Studio to version 3.0.1, but since then I can't see the layout of my application anymore. I can run my app, so the xml file is OK.I tried adding a new Virtual Device and updating my SDK, but I still can't see my layout. Has anyone faced this issue? Can I do anything to solve it out? Thanks.

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJgJK.png)

Comment: click on `<null>` and select

Comment: Does device listing is showing when you click <null>?

Comment: There are no options under <null>... I don't understand why...

Comment: I have same problem. did you get right solution ? 

There are no options under <null> Only "Automatically Pick Best".

Answer (score 0):

Try Clean and Rebuilding the project. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

.
change into any **api** level now it is in null

[image]

**Reference :** [Preview not Showing in Android 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512657/preview-not-showing-in-android-3-0-canary)
and

[Android Studio 3.0 xml-layout file's preview not showing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037141/android-studio-3-0-xml-layout-files-preview-not-showing-issue)

Comment: There are no option under <null>. I'm trying to add a new Virtual Device to see if it works...

Comment: OK..then you have to update your sdk.then only it will work

Comment: Adding a new Virtual Device and updating the SDK also did not work.

Comment: Please post your sdk,,I have to check

Comment: I clicked the button "Sinc project with Gradle files" and it is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by clicking the button "Sinc project with Gradle files". Now I can see my layout. Thanks to those who tried helping me.

Answer (score 0):

> **Your Solution is here**
>
> First you **Sync Your Project** (See in the image red highlighted circle) Click on the Icon
>
> ***See Below Image***
> [image]

Your problem is now fixed.